# Google Translate self blocking on some hosts?

Tags: google-translate

I've got some blocked attempts to load Google Translate on my website on some hosts.

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?client=te&alpha=true&hl=fr&cb=_callbacks____0jtr2z0a8' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

HTTP response is :

```
_callbacks____0jtr2z0a8({"sl":{"auto":"Détecter la langue","af":"Afrikaans","sq":"Albanais","de":"Allemand","am":"Amharique","en":"Anglais","ar":"Arabe","hy":"Arménien","az":"Azéri","eu":"Basque","bn":"Bengali","be":"Biélorusse","my":"Birman","bs":"Bosniaque","bg":"Bulgare","ca":"Catalan","ceb":"Cebuano","ny":"Chichewa","zh-CN":"Chinois","si":"Cingalais","ko":"Coréen","co":"Corse","ht":"Créole haïtien","hr":"Croate","da":"Danois","es":"Espagnol","eo":"Espéranto","et":"Estonien","fi":"Finnois","fr":"Français","fy":"Frison","gd":"Gaélique (Écosse)","gl":"Galicien","cy":"Gallois","ka":"Géorgien","el":"Grec","gu":"Gujarati","ha":"Haoussa","haw":"Hawaïen","iw":"Hébreu","hi":"Hindi","hmn":"Hmong","hu":"Hongrois","ig":"Igbo","id":"Indonésien","ga":"Irlandais","is":"Islandais","it":"Italien","ja":"Japonais","jw":"Javanais","kn":"Kannada","kk":"Kazakh","km":"Khmer","ky":"Kirghiz","ku":"Kurde","lo":"Laotien","la":"Latin","lv":"Letton","lt":"Lituanien","lb":"Luxembourgeois","mk":"Macédonien","ms":"Malaisien","ml":"Malayalam","mg":"Malgache","mt":"Maltais","mi":"Maori","mr":"Marathi","mn":"Mongol","nl":"Néerlandais","ne":"Népalais","no":"Norvégien","uz":"Ouzbek","ps":"Pachtô","pa":"Panjabi","fa":"Persan","pl":"Polonais","pt":"Portugais","ro":"Roumain","ru":"Russe","sm":"Samoan","sr":"Serbe","st":"Sesotho","sn":"Shona","sd":"Sindhî","sk":"Slovaque","sl":"Slovène","so":"Somali","su":"Soundanais","sv":"Suédois","sw":"Swahili","tg":"Tadjik","tl":"Tagalog","ta":"Tamoul","cs":"Tchèque","te":"Telugu","th":"Thaï","tr":"Turc","uk":"Ukrainien","ur":"Urdu","vi":"Vietnamien","xh":"Xhosa","yi":"Yiddish","yo":"Yorouba","zu":"Zoulou"},"tl":{"af":"Afrikaans","sq":"Albanais","de":"Allemand","am":"Amharique","en":"Anglais","ar":"Arabe","hy":"Arménien","az":"Azéri","eu":"Basque","bn":"Bengali","be":"Biélorusse","my":"Birman","bs":"Bosniaque","bg":"Bulgare","ca":"Catalan","ceb":"Cebuano","ny":"Chichewa","zh-CN":"Chinois (simplifié)","zh-TW":"Chinois (traditionnel)","si":"Cingalais","ko":"Coréen","co":"Corse","ht":"Créole haïtien","hr":"Croate","da":"Danois","es":"Espagnol","eo":"Espéranto","et":"Estonien","fi":"Finnois","fr":"Français","fy":"Frison","gd":"Gaélique (Écosse)","gl":"Galicien","cy":"Gallois","ka":"Géorgien","el":"Grec","gu":"Gujarati","ha":"Haoussa","haw":"Hawaïen","iw":"Hébreu","hi":"Hindi","hmn":"Hmong","hu":"Hongrois","ig":"Igbo","id":"Indonésien","ga":"Irlandais","is":"Islandais","it":"Italien","ja":"Japonais","jw":"Javanais","kn":"Kannada","kk":"Kazakh","km":"Khmer","ky":"Kirghiz","ku":"Kurde","lo":"Laotien","la":"Latin","lv":"Letton","lt":"Lituanien","lb":"Luxembourgeois","mk":"Macédonien","ms":"Malaisien","ml":"Malayalam","mg":"Malgache","mt":"Maltais","mi":"Maori","mr":"Marathi","mn":"Mongol","nl":"Néerlandais","ne":"Népalais","no":"Norvégien","uz":"Ouzbek","ps":"Pachtô","pa":"Panjabi","fa":"Persan","pl":"Polonais","pt":"Portugais","ro":"Roumain","ru":"Russe","sm":"Samoan","sr":"Serbe","st":"Sesotho","sn":"Shona","sd":"Sindhî","sk":"Slovaque","sl":"Slovène","so":"Somali","su":"Soundanais","sv":"Suédois","sw":"Swahili","tg":"Tadjik","tl":"Tagalog","ta":"Tamoul","cs":"Tchèque","te":"Telugu","th":"Thaï","tr":"Turc","uk":"Ukrainien","ur":"Urdu","vi":"Vietnamien","xh":"Xhosa","yi":"Yiddish","yo":"Yorouba","zu":"Zoulou"},"al":{}})
```

Works for years and on many hosts (Win/Mac/...). But for some days, I can't fully load Google Translate on some hosts (most works like always).
Seems not browser nor OS dependant.

Answer (score 0):

I delete the cookie "cookie: NID=179=S.........." and then, Google Translate is back !